# Spring security access denied message when accessing login page after login successfully.It should redirect to default page

Tags: spring-security

1. Configured spring security successfully
2. Authentication properly working
3. Problem is that after login successfully if user access login page, access denied message appears.It must redirect to default page as user already login.
   When i access login.html after login successfully , access denied message appears.
   Here's my code

---

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/services/**" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/stations.html" always-use-default-target="true" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login.html"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/common/**" filters="none"/>
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
       users-by-username-query="
          SELECT USERNAME,PASSWORD,USER_STATUS as ENABLED 
          from USERS where USERNAME=?" 

       authorities-by-username-query="
          SELECT USERNAME, USER_ROLE from USERS 
          where USERNAME =?  " 

    /> 
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 1):

When the user successfully loggs in this means he/she has some role (admin for example). This is different than ROLE_ANONYMOUS. You can try:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS, ROLE_ADMIN,..any other role" />
```

or even better

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login.html" filters="none" />
```

One suggestion: Spring Security evaluate the intercept-url elements in the order you write them in the xml, so you should put the most "greedy" intercept-url at the end. E.g. `<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />` will catch everything. The intercept-url for css, js... will never be reached. You should place them first.

Comment: Thanks 4 your help & suggestion.But my problem not solved.My problem is that when already login user access login page it must redirect to stations.html page .Does it possible in xml ? or I need to write code 4 this.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with xml. In the controller method mapped to the login page you can check the current user User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(); and redirect if you need.

Comment: I get it working only with the attribute `access="permitAll"` for the `intercept-url` tag related to the login form page instead of `filters="none"`. Indeed, `filters="none"` is no more supported in recent Spring Security releases: the suggested equivalent solution is to use another `http` element with `security="none"`, but it is not what you want because with it you are not able to distinguish authenticated access to the login page from non-authenticated access.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem,

I have already search many resources and did not found what I looking for.

At last, I'm doing this:

```
public class SSOInit extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SSOInit.class.getName());

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        logger.info("### SSO : doInit, read page");
        logger.info("### SSO : request url = " + request.getRequestURL());
        logger.info("### SSO : request method = " + request.getMethod());

        CredentialVO credential = SSOService.getUserCredential();
        if (credential != null) {
            logger.info("### SSO : credential found, do check point");
            String status = SSOService.checkSSOSessionKey();
            if (status == null || status.equals("T")) {
                logger.info("### SSO : Check point didn't passed, redirect");
                Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                if (auth != null) {
                    new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
                }
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
            } else {
                logger.info("### SSO : Check point passed");
                if (request.getServletPath().equals(SSOConstant.getREDIRECT_URL())) {
                    logger.info("### SSO : Check point passed, user trying access login form but already authenticated, redirect");
                    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + SSOConstant.getMAIN_URL());
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
}
```

and add this xml configuration to dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="ptpn4.rawi.sso.client.authentication.SSOInit" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

In class SSOInit, I do some checking to database, I'm trying to build Custom SSO Solution.

I hope another better solution regarding my current approach.